# Cannot change the boolean in table lua love2d

Tags: lua, require, game-development, love2d

I am creating a simple platformer with love2d in lua.
I want the player to stand on the ground so that it won't fall.

However I got some proablem that I cannot change the string of a table return from player.lua

(It is a table because the player.lua return m and the last sentance, and m is a table)

I tested that the isOnFloor function is work, but I just can't change the boolean in the player table.

Main.lua

```
local love = require("love")
local tileMapper = require("tile/tileMapper")
local player = require "player"

local isOnFloor = require("isOnFloor")

function love.load()

    love.window.setMode(1080, 640)

    love.window.setTitle("Simple Platformer")
 
    tileMapper:spawn()

    tiles = tileMapper.tiles

    player:setValue()

    love.keyboard.keyPressed = {}
     
end 

function love.update(dt)

    for i = 1, #tiles do
        
        if isOnFloor(player.x, player.y, tiles[i].x, tiles[i].y, 32, 32 * 3, 72, 72) then
 
            player.currentState = "ground" -- I wanna change it here but when I go back to 
 --player.lua and try to let it out put the self.currentState, nothing changed --
    
        else 

            player.currentState = "air"

        end

    end

    player:update(dt)
    
    love.keyboard.keyPressed = {}

end
```

I try to print out the player.currentState the the line after I set the player.currentState = "ground". It printed out "ground"

But if I print it in player.lua, it is always "air"

player.lua(I didn't paste some of the code here)

```
m = {}

function m:setValue()

    self.x = 400
    self.y = 50

    self.vtx = 0

    self.y_input = 0

    self.speed = 300
    self.jumpForce = -800
    self.gravity = 100

    self.anim = {idle = {img = love.graphics.newImage("assets/Idle.png"), maxFrame = 10},
                run = {img = love.graphics.newImage("assets/Run.png"), maxFrame = 11},
                jump = {img = love.graphics.newImage("assets/Jump.png"), maxFrame = 0},
                fall = {img = love.graphics.newImage("assets/Fall.png"), maxFrame = 0}}

    self.currentAnim = nil

    for i = 1, #self.anim do
        
        self.anim[i]:setFilter("nearest", "nearest")

    end

    self.frame = 0
    self.timer = 0

    self.currentState = nil

end

function m:update(dt)
    print(self.currentState)
    ---------------------- Player States Update ------------------------

    self:getXInput()

    if self.currentState == "ground" then

        if self.vtx == 0 then
            
            self.currentAnim = self.anim.idle

      
    elseif not(self.vtx == 0) then

            self.currentAnim = self.anim.run

        end
        
        
    elseif self.currentState == "air" then

        self.y_input = self.y_input + self.gravity

        if self.y_input > 0 then
           
            self.currentAnim = self.anim.fall

        elseif self.y_input < 0  then

            self.currentAnim = self.anim.jump

        end

    end

    ------------------------ Anim --------------------
    self:animUpdate(dt)


    if love.keyboard.keyPressed["space"] == true then
        
        self.y_input = self.jumpForce 

    end

    self.x = self.x + self.speed * dt * self.vtx
    self.y = self.y + self.y_input * dt
    
end

return m
```

If you have an idea of this porblem, please tell, thank you.

Comment: Since your player can touch  the ground as well as the air you might get a problem there. Clear your current state by setting to "air" once, then only set it to ground if you touch something.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be work now, thx. But still don't really understand why I would works lol